# Facebook Comment plugin is stuck perpetually loading -- is it Facebook or my code?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I am embedding Facebook Comment plugin on our site and for some reason the comment plugin is stuck in a perpetually loading sate like follows:

[image: Facebook comment plugin perpetual load]

I'm not sure if it's a Facebook problem or my code.  Here's what I have right after the opening `<body>` tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
      FB.init({ appId: '1234567890', cookie: true, oauth: true });
   };
   (function (d) {
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   } (document));
</script>
```

(1234567890 is where my actual appID is)

On the page where I want to show the Facebook comment plugin I have this:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://mydomain.com" 
     data-num-posts="2" data-width="580"></div>
```

As far as I can tell this should all work.  However, I've seen no mention of any FB bugs regarding this, nor do I see problems on other sites. So I guess it's my code?

I've even tried using the exact code given by the code generator on the FB developers site:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function (d, s, id) {
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1234567890";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work either.

Would love some help pointing me in the right direction!

**Update:** I've tried just placing my AppID in this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Rw79Q/) and it works. So there is something in my code causing the issue.  No idea what it could be and I can't share my entire code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
   ({ appId: '1234567890', cookie: true, oauth: true });
};
```

Isn't the body of that function actually supposed to be an argument? `({ appId: '1234567890', cookie: true, oauth: true });` in a function body creates an object literal and then does nothing with it. This is equivalent to writing:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {};
```

Which is useless.

The rest of your code looks like it works, but I don't have a valid app ID / domain on hand to test with at the moment. Drop your app ID and domain in this fiddle and see if it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Rw79Q/

---

From the chat discussion, it looks like the page has to be on a live server, otherwise you get the "infinite loading" behavior. I was able to recreate the behavior using a local `file:` URI. Hopefully the issue will go away once you push this to production.

Comment: I'm following this example as document here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ which uses `window.fbAsyncInit` the same way.

Comment: Your example is missing `FB.init`.

Comment: I updated my original question to include the mention that even if I remove the `window.fbAsyncInit` portion (which means I dn't need `FB.init`), it still doesn't solve it.

Comment: However, good catch. I tried adding in the FB.init but still not change in behavior.

Comment: @TMC did you try dropping your app ID into the fiddle I linked at the end of this answer?

Comment: it works in the fiddle with my app id. So it must be something on my page.. no idea what code could be causing a problem!

Comment: @TMC that's too bad... I don't think there's any other way to help without seeing the site or a reproduction of the problem. There's just too much guesswork involved.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11044/discussion-between-tmc-and-ggg)